# Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. Why is it undefined?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do `indexOf` on the array `powerfulAgainst`, inside the object `card`.

When I do `console.log(key)`, aaa is returned.

`console.log(card)` returns

```
[ { key: 'aaa',
        counteredBy: [],
        powerfulAgainst: [ 'bbb' ] } ]
```

Lastly, `console.log(card.powerfulAgainst)` returns `undefined` (even though it shouldn't, according to `console.log(card)`). Therefore, I obviously get the `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` error.

Why is this happening?

```
        var counters = originalCard["counteredBy"];
        var powerfuls = originalCard["powerfulAgainst"];
        counters.forEach(key => {
            var card = cards.filter(function (obj) {
                return obj.key == key;
            })
            if(card.length > 0) { 
                    if(card.powerfulAgainst.indexOf(key) < 0) {
                        card.powerfulAgainst.push(key);
                    } else { console.log(card.key + " is already powerful against " + key); }
            }
```

Comment: `card` is an array, not an object with a `powerfulAgainst` property. The object you're looking for is at `card[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cards` is an array. To access its property you need to pass the `index`. Since it is array of only one object, and since index starts from 0 `cards[0]` access the first object

```js
var cards = [{
  key: 'aaa',
  counteredBy: [],
  powerfulAgainst: ['bbb']
}]

console.log(cards[0].powerfulAgainst)
```

Comment: I thought `cards.filter()` returned a single object if it only found one occurrence. Thank you.

Comment: `cards.filter()` returns an array as the others said. To achieve what you want, you need to use `cards.find()`, which returns the _first_ match.

Answer (score 1):

On the line where you get the error `card` is an array of cards, not a card itself, so it does not have a `.powerfulAgainst` property.